# C# XmlDocument for small XML files - weight / performance

Tags: c#, performance, xmldocument

I wondering about sense of using XmlDocument class to processing a small XML files.
If during the XML file is loading, XmlDocument creates a whole set of object-oriented structure for all XML elements and their relationship, theoretically for small xml files, there is a slight performance decrease and resources consumption and in the same time, we have clear and easy data management.

I read many articles about the processing of XML files - usualy people suggest using  lightweight solutions like XmlTextReader instead XmlDocument for fast forward reading - even for small files. Am I wrong or XmlDocument is not so bad?

Comment: Why don't you run some benchmarks on your files? You can compare the performance of `XmlDocument` vs `XmlTextReader` and find out for yourself.

Comment: have you considered the use of Linq to XML?!?

Comment: Have you also considered using XDocument (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) ? It will make it real easy to manipulate your small XML files using LINQ...

Comment: It depends on what exactly do you need, but take a look here http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html and even here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304314/why-would-native-code-called-from-net-give-different-result-from-calling-it-from

Comment: @Oded: I talk about good practice - my experience can't be complete so I could say, that this what I get, is more universal than my test case.

Comment: @UGEEN - good practice is to measure for you usage and use the right tool/class for the job.

Comment: @Oded: I just want to avoid the situation in which I've made a mistake thinking that mistake was little

Comment: That's why you need to measure for _your_ situation, with your usage scenario.

Comment: @Oded: yes it's necessary anyway - but I just wanted to realize the disatvantages of general use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to measure it, but even for a small file the I/O will be the main factor.

And how do you want to use the file? That is far more important.

I would never consider an Xml(Text)Reader for small files. The only thing it would optimize is memory usage.

---

In reply to the comment:

For 100kB, just use XDocument or the older XmlDocument

You can get all your nodes with XElement.Descendants("TAG")

```
  var xmlData = XDocument.Load(filename);
  var tags = xmlData.Descendants("TAG");
  foreach(var tag in tags) ...
```

Comment: Yes - I can't bypass I/O factor. I want to call SelectNodes("//TAG") and have fast access to nodes list collection. File is small (~ 100 kb)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is personal preference. Personally speaking I have used Xmldocument over XmlTextReader as I find it easier to work with. I have moved to use LINQ to Xml now as it uses XDocument which allows easier reading of nodes and elements

have a read of this 5 minute introduction to LINQ to Xml as it is a lot easier to use and to read http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx